# How to determine which ListView a delegate QML Item is in?

Tags: qml, qt5

I have two ListViews (selection and queue) which both use the same delegate.

I want to present some of the item information differently between the two lists.

How do I determine which ListView a QML Item is in? There is no item.parent I can access in the QML.

Comment: What about [ListView.view](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#view-attached-prop) attached property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ListView.view` attached property as folibis mentioned, but there is a nicer way. If you move the delegate into its own QML file, say, `Delegate.qml`, you can create instances of that type that simply set a property that changes their appearances.

For example:

```
ListView {
    // ...
    delegate: Delegate {
        fancy: true
    }
}

ListView {
    // ...
    delegate: Delegate {
        fancy: false
    }
}
```

You'd code `Delegate` in such a way that it knows how to render a fancy/non-fancy delegate. For example:

```
Rectangle {
    property bool fancy

    color: fancy ? "steelblue" : "grey"
    // ...
}
```

Comment: yeah - the delegate is already in a separate qml file - thanks